# Postgres: UPSERT or INCREMENTAL update of a large table

Tags: sql, postgresql, etl, data-warehouse, upsert

I have a following problem.

We have two systems, an OLTP system and our Data Warehouse, both on PostgreSQL. I need to sync one table from OLTP system with DWH, so they're identical. I am using Foreign Data Wrapper for comunication between databases, so then sync could be straightforward and look like that:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE target_table;
INSERT INTO target_table SELECT * FROM source_table;
```

Unfortunately, the table is huge for the hardware we use (hundreds of millions of rows, and about 50GB of data), so this is massively time consuming.

I have then figured out a way to do it faster by doing incremental upsert, based on following approach.

1. Identify new rows in source table by taking rows with `insert_time > SELECT max(insert_time) FROM target_table;`.
2. Identify rows, that need to be updated, by joining both tables on `id` and `source_table.update_time > target_table.update_time`.

That worked absolutely fine, however, a new problem arised - rows from source table can be removed, therefore I need to remove corresponding rows from target table. All approaches I tried are way to slow, like this one for example:

```
CREATE VIEW deleted_rows AS SELECT
target.row_id
FROM target
LEFT JOIN source USING(id)
WHERE source.id IS NULL;
```

Any idea how to solve this problem smartly and quickly? Thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: Truncate and re-load is often the fastest approach when there are a lot of changes to a table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, still to slow. There are also several indices on the table, that make it even slower.

Comment: Remove all index , rebuild, recreate indexes, never bulk insert with indexes or triggers in place. Turn off logging if possible .safest approach is complete rebuild. Doing incremental is prone to errors. Also don’t use > for your date logic, you have problems where by two rows with same time may exist but only one was picked up in prior build due to timings.

Comment: @AbBennett actually due to the reason you provided i switched to id which is based on a sequence.

Comment: Works if no records are ever updated, prone to error if s record missed for some reason. Why not just do the inverse of your delete to I’d new records. What if the Dba of your source systems decided to archive some data after 7 years or so. Do you want the dwh to follow suit?

Comment: @AbBennett for update i may use >= instead of >, that is not a problem at all. The real problem is in identyfying rows present in target, but absent in source.

Comment: Drop indexes and do a rebuild, and see what the time is.

Comment: @AbBennett the reverse of my delete statement will be way to slow. Comparing id to max id uses indices and is quite fast. Using not exists, not in or LEFT JOIN / WHERE x IS NULL is way slower.

Comment: If you can Garuntee  a record may never be missed. Ie your max in dwh  is 10 but for whatever reason you are missing 9, Anyway your asking advice, I’ve seen this errors happen time and time again, I’d go a full rebuild given your delete logic may be slow anyway. If time is an issue use your max logic, and leave deleted records in your dwh, does it matter if they persist. Once they have made their way into a fact table they will persist anyway.

Comment: If there are a lot of idempotent updates (source and target row are exactly the same) , you can gain a lot by suppressing these, avoiding the *write amplification*.

Comment: My proposal is to create a table for keeping the IDs of the deleted rows. Whenever you delete a source row write a record to this table. Every once in a while use this table as a guide to delete target rows and trunc the table. You can either update your app to write to this table or use a trigger.

Comment: BTW: you should add the definitions for the tables, your update/delete statements and the resulting query plans to the question (I get the feeling that your source table doesn't have any usable indices or statistics)

Comment: have you tried trigger with function deleting record from foreign table on a master table update?

Comment: @JustMe, that would be great. Unfortunately I am not responsble for source system.

Comment: @PawełSopel Well, maybe function with cursor determining missing ids will be faster than joining?